# Why my transaction failed : error -3200

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, uniswap, bsc

I'm trying to developp my first smart contract to make some arbitrage between DEX.

I started by using the code from :
https://github.com/pugzly/token_swap/blob/main/token_swap.sol

But when I execute the swap function with :
_tokenIn : WBNB address
_tokenOut : BUSD address
_amountIn: 0x038d7ea4c68000 //0.001 WBNB
_amountOutMin : from getAmountMin function
_to : My address

I have an error with gas estimation but impossible for me to understand why :
[image]

Here is my code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router {
  function getAmountsOut(uint256 amountIn, address[] memory path)
    external
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
  
  function swapExactTokensForTokens(
    uint256 amountIn,
    uint256 amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint256 deadline
  ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Pair {
  function token0() external view returns (address);
  function token1() external view returns (address);
  function swap(
    uint256 amount0Out,
    uint256 amount1Out,
    address to,
    bytes calldata data
  ) external;
}


contract ArbitrageV1{
    event approve(uint256 buy1,uint256 _montant);
    event estimate(uint256 montan);
    address private constant routerPCS = 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E;
    address private constant wbnb1=0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;

    
    function swap(address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amountIn, uint256 _amountOutMin, address _to) external {
        IERC20(_tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountIn);
    
        IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(routerPCS, _amountIn);

        address[] memory path;
        if (_tokenIn == wbnb1 || _tokenOut == wbnb1) {
            path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = _tokenOut;
        } else {
            path = new address[](3);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = wbnb1;
            path[2] = _tokenOut;
        }
        IUniswapV2Router(routerPCS).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amountIn, _amountOutMin, path, _to, block.timestamp);
    }receive() payable external {}
    
    function getAmountOutMin(address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amountIn) external view returns (uint256) {
        address[] memory path;
        if (_tokenIn == wbnb1 || _tokenOut == wbnb1) {
            path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = _tokenOut;
        } else {
            path = new address[](3);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = wbnb1;
            path[2] = _tokenOut;
        }
        uint256[] memory amountOutMins = IUniswapV2Router(routerPCS).getAmountsOut(_amountIn, path);
        return amountOutMins[path.length -1];
    } 
    }
```

I would be very greatful if you can help me,

**UPDATE** :
Thanks for your answer Rihe, I just changed my gas settings but it still doesn't work.
[image]

**UPDATE 2 :**
Thanks again, I just removed the transferFrom line as you recommended me.

I still have the Gas Estimation failed error, but it's more detailed :
[image]

I know that this error is generally linked to approve problem. Do you have any idea to solve it ?

Comment: What are the gas price settings?

Comment: There is no gas settings, I don't find where to put it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your gas settings are incorrect. In the Remix IDE you can fix it easily. Please find the below image. I think something like *300000* for **gaslimit** and *5 gwei* for **value** should be fine[image].

**UPDATE**

After checking your code I observed that your swap function may be incorrect. When you call the `swapExactTokensForTokens`, you don't have to manually make a transfer. The router will handle it. You just need to approve it.

```
function swap(address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amountIn, uint256 _amountOutMin, address _to) external {    
    IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(routerPCS, _amountIn);
address[] memory path;
if (_tokenIn == wbnb1 || _tokenOut == wbnb1) {
    path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = _tokenIn;
    path[1] = _tokenOut;
} else {
    path = new address[](3);
    path[0] = _tokenIn;
    path[1] = wbnb1;
    path[2] = _tokenOut;
}
IUniswapV2Router(routerPCS).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amountIn, _amountOutMin, path, _to, block.timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question with your suggestion but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: It is not easy without the full code. BTW other thing I see is that you make a transfer before approving the token in your swap function. That will cause an error too. @Flavien

Comment: This is my full code, only using this function swap. Yes, I saw that when I only ask approve function, there is no problem, but when I use TransferFrom there is the gas issue. So do you recommend me to put my Approve before my TransferFrom ? Thx

Comment: The approve is to allow the contract to spend my tokens on PCS router. But I don't understand if I need to approve the contract for my wallet before transferFrom, if yes, idk where to do it

Comment: @Flavien I added a modified version from your code. The point is you don't have to make the transfer in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I still have a problem with the TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED error, I just uptaded my post. Maybe an approve is missing or miswritten?

Comment: @Flavien Something must be with your tx. It can be several thing, as it is a new error I suggest to post it as new question if you think your original question has been answered here. However for the first sight I find the value of _amountIn: 0x038d7ea4c68000 problematic. You should use int in wei instead of 0x038d7ea4c68000 .